Extensions in subdirectories are not excluded in Zip archive
I have a folder with many sub directories I want to exclude some extensions, but they are only excluded from the first directory level, how to exclude from all directories.
Example of Directory (simplified)
dir: 
  - a.exe
  - z.dll
  - q.dat
  - dir1: 
    - g.exe
    - y.dll
    - r.dat

I don't want any of these extensions only the files not in dir1 are excluded.
Code (simplified)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\dir" -Exclude @('*.exe','*.dll', '*.dat')

Compress-Archive            `
  -Update                   `
  -Path $files              `
  -CompressionLevel Fastest `
  -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop"

The zip file contains the extensions in dir1.

Sounds like you're just missing -Recurse in your Get-ChildItem call, however by doing so your Zip file will just contain files, the folder hierarchy is lost

Are you looking to preserve the folder hierarchy in your Zip while excluding the files ?

oops I had it with recurse as well (I thought that might've been the problem) and it still doesn't work, I get all the folders correctly, but in dir2 the files with extensions are still there. Another problem is that I don't get the top level folder, since I'm using Get-ChildItem anyway to fix that? Yes I guess so @SantiagoSquarzon How would you go about this? I actually need the top level dir name as this is a function which I apply to a few different dirs, but I just narrowed the problem down.

Yes I just re-checked and the subdirs still have the files with extensions, anyway, interested to see how you'd go about this @SantiagoSquarzon

Compress-Archive doesn't have an -Exclude by itself to help you with this, by using -Exclude @('*.exe', '*.dll', '*.dat') with Get-ChildItem you're excluding files with those extensions in your $files variable, however because dir1 is included then all files in that folder are also compressed.
I'd recommend to try Compress-ZipArchive instead which does have an -Exclude parameter. This way you retain the folder hierarchy while also excluding the files having those extensions:
$compressZipArchiveSplat = @{
    Path             = "$env:USERPROFILE\dir"
    Update           = $true
    CompressionLevel = 'Fastest'
    Destination      = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop"
    Exclude          = '*.exe', '*.dll', '*.dat'
}

Compress-ZipArchive @compressZipArchiveSplat

This cmdlet is from PSCompression Module, you can install it from the Gallery:
Install-Module PSCompression -Scope CurrentUser


With the original code I always get the extensions in the sub dirs, (not in the first dir) even if I use it with Copy-Item seems like this shouldn't happen but it does. Are you saying that I would get no folders and only files with my code? I get files and folders. Giving this a go now thanks.

This worked perfectly, with my code I got 30mb, with no exclude 137mb, with this 2.5 mb which is ideal for uploading, many thanks, also solved the problem of the top level dir name.

@Nickotine my bad, i don't know why i thought you were using -File in Get-ChildItem. I have updated my answer to explain the issue but basically because dir1 folder is included in the output from Get-ChildItem then all files in that folder are also compressed

Oh right I see. Much appreciated, this stupid script took way too much of my time... I'd have had it done in 2 mins if It was bash, thank you. Need to level up my powershell.
